# the program works but its incorrect and not sure where going wrong

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to answer the questions shown for my homework but not sure where going wrong: These days it’s common to find a criminal by finding a match of their

DNA with a `computer database`. Oddly DNA is a code like computer
code but the code is written in 4 ‘base pairs’ called  (G,T,A,C).

We can store DNA on a computer by decoding it and storing it
in an array `( G=0,T=1,A=2,C=3 )` so a DNA sample can be stored in an
`integer array int DNA[] = { 1,3,2,1,1,2,0,2,3,3,3 } ;` except much much 
longer (millions of base pairs make up a single gene). Write a function called `HW2F` called which takes two DNA arrays. One is called sample the
other criminal. If the sequences match then return a boolean true 
( found criminal match) or  false ( not this sample).So

```
      public boolean HW2F( int sample[] , int criminal[ ] ) 
       {

        for(int i=0; i < sample.length; i++) 
        {
                if(sample[i] == criminal[i])
                {
                    return true;   

                }  
         } 
                return false;   
       }
```

no error message as program works but doesnt retrun correct values

Comment: Java != Javascript.

Comment: ops wrong tag sorry

Comment: You only need one loop. Currently you are comparing every position in s with every position in c, but you want to compare only s[i] with c[i]. And you only can short-circuit return if you find a false value! (Assuming both have the sam size!)

Comment: both arrays are the same size as infor this example we are compearing DNA so there are both 12 char long i belive

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/G8rmj2e

Comment: Compare if they are not equal to return early! Both sequences are equal, when every position is equal, so you can only say that if you tested the whole sequence! When there is a difference anywhere in the sequences, you can early `return false`. Oh, and please don't post screenshots, [edit] your question. (Well, okay, I should not use comments to answer your question ;))

Comment: im sorry dont quite get what you mean

Comment: When are the two sequences equal? When they are equal for every element (`s[i] == c[i]`). So you have to test every element to `return true`. They are unequal when there is (at least) one position where `s[i] != c[i]`. Then you can `return false`. IOW: You have to "switch" your if statement and your return values.

Comment: thank you very much, took me a little to while to get what you meant just becuase im dylesix alot and strugle with reading, even though im 20 hahah. thank you alot though

Comment: in other words, as soon as you find a difference you return `false`; otherwise loop to the end and only then return `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs a small tweak, *Here is the complete code*

```
public boolean HW2F(int sample[], int criminal[]) {

        for (int i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
            if (sample[i] != criminal[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```